# python create new folder only if requirement meets

Tags: python

my current code does

1. create a new folder(if not already exist)
2. split .dat file into smaller .dat files by group and put them in the new folder

```
newpath = r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python split\test\437599'
newpath = r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python split\test\451295'
newpath = r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python split\test\462888'


for filename in glob.glob(f"*{extension}"):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if '4375 99' in line:
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)
                with open(os.path.join(newpath, '437599.dat'), 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(line)

for filename in glob.glob(f"*{extension}"):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if '4512 95' in line:
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)
                with open(os.path.join(newpath, '451295.dat'), 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(line)

for filename in glob.glob(f"*{extension}"):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if '4628 88' in line:
                if not os.path.exists(newpath):
                    os.makedirs(newpath)
                with open(os.path.join(newpath, '462888.dat'), 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

how do i:

1. create the new folder only if the requirement (if '4628 88' in line:) is met
2. smaller .dat files is created inside its own new folder with the same name

current output problem:

new folder created: \451295
inside the folder: 437599.dat, 451295.dat, 462888.dat

Comment: Put the code that makes the directory inside `if '4628 88' in line:`

Comment: You're not putting the output file inside `newpath`

Answer (score 1):

Move the code that creates the folder and opens the output file inside the `if`.

Add a list of all the codes you need to look for in the lines, and use this to construct the filenames as well.

```
newpath = r'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python split'
codes = ['4375 99', '4512 95', '4628 88']

for filename in glob.glob(f"*{extension}"):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            for code in codes:
                if code in line:
                    fname = code.replace(' ', '')
                    outdir = os.path.join(newpath, fname)
                    if not os.path.exists(outdir):
                        os.makedirs(newpath)
                        with open(os.path.join(outdir, f'{fname}.dat'), 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(line)
                    break
```

Comment: there's multiple newpath, and when i try your code, it only create one new folder and put everything into the new created folder, including the smaller .dat files that were supposed to be in their own folder.

Comment: Where do the multiple newpath come from?

Comment: sorry sir, i've edited my code as per the answer you share above

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you can't set `newpath` to 3 different things. Do you have them in a list? I notice that the last part of `newpath` is always the same as the `.dat` filename. Why not just loop over that and use it in both places?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a list of the codes.